# How to remove duplicate records based off a date/time timestamp column using tidyverse? R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("12/7/2021 11:29:15", "12/7/2021 11:29:35", 
                                     "12/7/2021 11:59:18", "12/7/2021 12:28:53", 
                                     "12/7/2021 13:19:12"), 
                        ID = c(157767, 380925, 319956, 375889, 375889), 
                        Status = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes")), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df",                                                                                             
                        "tbl", "data.frame"))

print(data)
> data
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Timestamp              ID Status
  <chr>               <dbl> <chr> 
1 12/7/2021 11:29:15 157767 Yes   
2 12/7/2021 11:29:35 380925 No    
3 12/7/2021 11:59:18 319956 Yes   
4 12/7/2021 12:28:53 375889 No    
5 12/7/2021 13:19:12 375889 Yes
```

Rows 4 & 5 have the same ID. Based off the TimeStamp, I can see that row 5 was done later and has and updated status.

Is it possible for me to filter based off timestamp to only show the most recent timestamps in my data frame? my Desired output would be the following

```
  Timestamp              ID Status
  <chr>               <dbl> <chr> 
1 12/7/2021 11:29:15 157767 Yes   
2 12/7/2021 11:29:35 380925 No    
3 12/7/2021 11:59:18 319956 Yes      
4 12/7/2021 13:19:12 375889 Yes
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr::slice_max` you could do:

Note: As your `Timestamp` is a character we first have to convert to a datetime to make this work (Thanks to @utubun for pointing that out in his comment)

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice_max(as.POSIXct(Timestamp, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Timestamp)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   Timestamp              ID Status
#>   <chr>               <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 12/7/2021 11:29:15 157767 Yes   
#> 2 12/7/2021 11:29:35 380925 No    
#> 3 12/7/2021 11:59:18 319956 Yes   
#> 4 12/7/2021 13:19:12 375889 Yes
```

Comment: It's not save without conversion to date, e.g. `max(c('12/7/2021 13:19:12', '12/10/2021 13:09:12'))` results to `"12/7/2021 13:19:12"`, because characters are ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @utubun. Thx. Haven't realized that Timestamp isn't a date time already. Will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

1. First transform `Timestamp` to `dttm` class.
2. group and filter by `last()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp = dmy_hms(Timestamp)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(Timestamp == last(Timestamp))
```

```
  Timestamp               ID Status
  <dttm>               <dbl> <chr> 
1 2021-07-12 11:29:15 157767 Yes   
2 2021-07-12 11:29:35 380925 No    
3 2021-07-12 11:59:18 319956 Yes   
4 2021-07-12 13:19:12 375889 Yes 
``´
```